# My website on heroku which uses multer to upload form files on server is automatically deleting my files after some time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, amazon-s3

I use **multer** and save my **pdf** files to the upload folder on the **heroku server** but these files are deleted after some time so i want to save these files permanently to some other space. Can you help me by telling some free **cloud service** and how can i interact to the service with my `node/express` code.

Comment: are you uploading your files into your public directory ? or to a tmp folder ?

Comment: In a temporary folder